# TUniTable/TFDTable.Filter wildcard limitation - like '[AB]*'

Tags: ms-access, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, unidac

Please help me with filter option.

Is it possible to use the wildcard option `Client like '[AB] *'` for records that start with 'A' or 'B'? This option works in Access, but it does not work in Unidac Table or FireDac Table as Filter.

Comment: So MS Access is not even involved in this issue? If so, remove the tag.

Comment: Why do you show a space in front of *? Try % instead of *.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is use FilterSQL, Unidac(8*), in Unidac 9* is this problem fixed (i think)
https://www.devart.com/unidac/revision_history.html

```
Client like '%p[o,ó]k[u,ú,ů][s,š]%'
```